# Byte alignment conflict with third party library in C++

Tags: c++

Now the byte alignment in my current project in VS2008 is 1 byte. And the there is one third party library I want to use it in my project, but the byte alignment of it is default alignment 4 bytes.

How to solve this byte alignment conflict? without changing the byte alignment of my project and the third party library.

Here is my solution

```
#pragma pack (push)
#pragma pack (1)

#include <amqp_tcp_socket.h>
#include <amqp.h>
#include <amqp_framing.h>

#pragma pack (pop)
```

But it seems not working well...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `amqp` is the third-party library, you need to tell the compiler what the alignment is for *that* code: `pack(4)`.